# Prince Rupert to Port Hardy ferry - questions about amenities

Tags: canada, ferries, british-columbia

We're contemplating a coastal British Columbia trip by car and will need to ride some ferries.  One ferry will be the Prince Rupert to Port Hardy ferry, between the north central B.C. coast and the northern end of Vancouver Island.  I know this is about a 16-hour ferry ride and the costs are decently documented [here](https://www.bcferries.com/fares/), with cabin costs and options documented [here](http://www.bcferries.com/travel_planning/fares/northern_vessel_cabin_rates.html).

I have some questions about the amenities and circumstances.  Being a 16-hour ferry ride, we're going to want to sleep (the ferry leaves Prince Rupert at about 10 pm and arrives in Port Hardy at about 2 pm the following day).  The questions all relate well enough so I'll ask them together here:

- Are inboard and outboard cabins identical, except that inboard lack a sea view and the outboard ones have one?
- Is there much difference in the sleeping comfort between the double beds and the single beds + pull-out sofa?  We are two married adults, but for the sake of future readers, feel free to answer all the sleeping scenarios.
- The daytime voyages have a "reserved seating" option - what is the advantage of this?  Could a person just stay in their cabin for the voyage?
- How much nicer are the "luxury" cabins compared to the normal cabins?

Also, I assume there won't be any Internet access on the ship, either through WiFi or cellular networks.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

From recent experience, regarding the BC Coast, there is minimal cell network coverage on the BC coast north of Port Hardy - there are spots near Bella Bella, Klemtu, Hartley Bay, and approaching Prince Rupert. It's been too many years since I took BC Ferries from Pt Hardy to Prince Rupert, so I don't know about the current accommodations or onboard WiFi - but it's an amazing trip. Enjoy!